# Matplotlib module not found error in Python3.6.9 in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, matplotlib, module, ubuntu-18.04

I have already installed matplotlib using pip command and now running pip doesn't install it but when trying to import matplotlib.pyplot then it's showing error that module not found.
I am on Ubuntu 18.04 and Python version 3.6.9

Comment: Please add more detail to the question, in particular whether you are running pip as root to try to update the system-wide installation or are using a virtual environment. It would be helpful to see the output of `which pip` at installation time, and `which python` at run time, to check that you are using the same environment in both cases.

Comment: Might it be that you need to import matplotlib using pip3?

Comment: Please try using this: `from matplotlib import pyplot`. Also, as sugegsted by @piet confirm if the script is being executed using python3 and not any other version of python installed in your system.

Comment: Thanks everyone it seems I was having problem with Python version as now I this time I tried installing it with sudo command as sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib and now it's working.